# jQuery: $(template) vs .clone()

Tags: jquery, templates

Lets say we have a complex string `template` (maybe a div containing lots of other tags..) and we need to add this HTML node multiple times to our existing document.

Will it be faster to create the HTML nodes from the template each time

```
var $html = $(template); // 1st run
var $html = $(template); // 2st run
...
```

or to only create them once and then clone them:

```
var $template = $(template); // init
var $html = $template.clone() // 1st run
var $html = $template.clone() // 2st run
...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a template seems to be consistently faster for short templates than a clone on all browsers tested so far except Opera (one test case, equal performance). Thank you all for the test cases.

http://jsperf.com/clone-versus-template

***update:***

this is the test with a long template and template built with jQuery:

http://jsperf.com/clone-versus-template/4

**this last test shows that the clone method far outperforms the template method** on Chrome, Firefox and Opera alike, but they are equal in IE9

Comment: Clone is 22% slower than template on the current Firefox as well.

Comment: Clone is 6% slower in Chromium. But with more complex content it is significantly faster: [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/clone-versus-template/2)

Comment: Thanks for setting up the test case. But it is not exactly reflecting what I need. I really need this call to `$(template)` since I need to modify the generated HTML nodes (add event handlers etc..). I updated the tests, seems to change to results: http://jsperf.com/clone-versus-template/3

Comment: @lrsjng thanks, I'll run the third revision through my browsers

Comment: @lrsjng perhaps you wanted to use the longer template provided by `nrodic`?

Comment: ahem... the template by `nrodic` does not properly clean up. The tests should not have persistent side-effects. One more test?

Comment: Sorry, it was quick copy/paste from this question. Could test again.

Comment: Unfortunately, the links don’t work anymore. Well, it’s almost ten years on… 